# Detect or Approximate Bluetooth Latency on Android (Audio Playback)

Tags: android, audio, youtube, bluetooth, latency

I am currently working on an Android audio visualizer using connected smart home devices (such as Philips hue) to visualize music. I have trouble compensating the delay caused by bluetooth speakers.

I have noticed, that the Youtube app, in difference to many other video streaming apps, has almost no delay between audio and video, when using bluetooth speakers.
I figure, that they must compensate for the bluetooth latency by adjusting (delaying) the video signal.

**Is there a reasonable way of detecting or approximating the latency/delay of bluetooth speakers?**

Thank you very much for you help!!

Best,
Stefan

Comment: It seems like YouTube may be using https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/ for playback, which has some code to detect audio latency: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/audio/AudioTrack.java#L801

Comment: Damn, seems that's not quite enough!  Their `AudioTrack` implementation reports positions about two seconds behind reality in my car.

Comment: Well actually, YouTube is off by a couple seconds too in my car, so maybe that's as good as possible.

Comment: Updated ExoPlayer link: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/b5beb32618ac99adc58b537031a6f7c3dd761b9a/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/audio/AudioTrackPositionTracker.java#L172 - They ask android.media.AudioTrack for the getLatency method.

Comment: Apart from source code strewn around the web, some documentation on AudioTrack getLatency here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/audio-video-synchronization.html#section1-2

Answer (score 2):

This would not work for Bluetooth *speakers*. However, I have been able to measure the audio latency of a Bluetooth dongle using Google's [Dr. Rick O'Rang loopback dongle](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/loopback.html), using [Glenn Kasten test app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.drrickorang.loopback&hl=en).

Comment: As clever as this is, a software solution would be ideal.  As the question states, somehow the YouTube app is able to do it.

Comment: I have been using this technique to measure the typical audio latency and found out, that it varies quite significantly between different Android devices. At this point I still have no clue on how the Youtube app is able to very accurately compensate for this. Any creative ideas?

Comment: How feasible would it be to build a device latency database and embed it in the app?

Answer (score 0):

AVDTP 1.3 protocol supports delay reporting. Try looking to see if Android exports this data.

It's in the somewhere: AVDT_PSC_DELAY_RPT is present in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/stack/include/avdt_api.h#153.

Comment: Hi There. Link based answers can be made into comments for better reach.

Comment: Link is broken. Do you have a different reference?