# Approximating audio latency in iOS for airplay, bluetooth and related technologies

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, airplay

Is there a method of determining the delay in audio when playing to bluetooth (or some other device, like airplay) on iOS?

I've searched and found a few things. The [advanced audio distribution spec](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=260859&vId=290074), for example, makes several references to "delay" reporting, but I'm not clear how to access this from iOS in the more general case of audio playback to some device.

If there were a method, iOS would use that method to play videos with the audio and video in sync which it doesn't seem to do. However, I do see some references to other systems being able to compensate for this (eg apparently the android YouTube player can compensate: [Detect or Approximate Bluetooth Latency on Android (Audio Playback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139179/detect-or-approximate-bluetooth-latency-on-android-audio-playback))

Comment: I think the latency is random.

Comment: Some codecs are specifically designed for low-latency BT use. In testing, some of my devices have noticeably and consistently more latency than others.

Comment: `CoreBluetooth.framework` is for Bluetooth Low-Energy (only). And BLE is not suited for Audio. So is the tag correct?

Comment: @larme I'm not sure. It was a reasonable part of the question (since I didn't realize that), and a reasonable answer might include your comment -- I'm not sure what StackOverflow's policy would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this issue myself. [AvAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession) provides properties for [outputLatency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616500-outputlatency)
as well as [inputLatency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616537-inputlatency). I do see differences in the values when I connect to a pair of bluetooth headphones, vs the iPhone microphone and speaker, though I cannot speak to how accurate these numbers are.